# Does a path connected ordered space imbed into the long line?

Tags: general-topology

"Long line" in this post refers to "the line which is long in both directions".

If $X$ has the order topology and is path connected, does $X$ imbed into the long line? In other words... is the long line the longest line? Note that the long line is path connected.

This seems plausible since any space formed by the dictionary order on $o \times [0,1)$ is not path connected for an ordinal $o$ greater than $\omega_1$.

Answer (score 0):

We show that a path connected ordered space $X_C$ with a minimal element imbeds into the long closed ray $L_{C} = \omega_1 \times [0,1)$. Note that every totally ordered set has a cofinal well-ordered subset. For such $A \subset X_{C}$ consider for each $a \in A$ the set $I_{a} = [a, \mathrm{Succ}(a)) \subset X_{C}$, where $\mathrm{Succ}$ denotes the successor function on $A$. Each $I_a$ is homeomorphic to $[0,1)$ because $X_{C}$ is path connected. Then $X_C = \bigcup_{a \in  A}I_{a}$ is homeomorphic to $o \times [0,1)$ for some ordinal $o$. From the plausibility comment in the question post we know that $o \leq \omega_1$ and so $X_C$ imbeds into $L_C$.

Then for an arbitrary path connected ordered space $X \neq \varnothing$, we imbed it into the long line by taking some element $x \in X$ and essentially performing the previous argument on both $(-\infty,x]$ and $[x,\infty)$ where the proper dual notions are used in the first case.